# How to resume iCloud restore?

Tags: iphone, icloud, restore

I formatted my iPhone and after setting up iCloud, my apps and pictures were downloading.

In middle due to net disconnection, it stopped and it's in stop state till now.

Apps icons are dim and lots of pictures have empty frame.

How do I start downloading/resume them again?

Comment: Click on one of them to check if they start downloading again.

Comment: @Rob you might be referring to apps, but i want the pictures downloaded.

Comment: That's not what you asked in the question. You claim both stopped to work.

Comment: @Rob I understand the app resume, when you tap. What about the pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

1. Settings
2. Reset
3. Reset All Settings

and the process will start over. You're **not losing content** this way, because that's the 2nd option on that page.

Answer (score -3):

Erase again and restore again. This is the only way for now

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: This isn't the only way for me. Could you explain why resetting settings or contacting Apple support wouldn't solve this? A total erase might work, too so be sure to explain when or how that worked for you to improve the quality of this answer